# Getting all the records from Patient entity with primary insurance of the patient can be 'P' that is primary

Tags: mysql, jpql

I want the following SQL query in `JQPL` syntax:

```
select P.*,PIN.INSURANCE_COMPANY_ID
from PATIENT_INSURANCE PIN 
right join PATIENT P ON (PIN.Patient_ID = P.ID 
and PIN.INSURANCE_TYPE = 'P' AND PIN.STATUS = 'A')
where P.STATUS = 'A'
```

Please help.

Comment: Your question is vague and there is unclear connection to the sample you have pasted. Please provide clear background, specify what are you trying to do, what is the problem and what help you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
  p.id,
  p.lastName,
  p.firstName,
  p.middleName,
  p.dob,
  p.sex,
  p.ssn,
  p.phone,
  p.status,
  pi.insuranceCompanyId ,
  IF(pi.insuranceType ='P' , 'is P', 'is not P')
from 
  PatientInsurance pi 
right join Patient p 
  on pi.patientID = p.id
```

Or if you want all the records that have `pi.insuranceType ='P'` you can append to the query :
`WHERE pi.insuranceType ='P'`

Comment: I have PATIENT TABLE AND PATIENT_INSURANCE TABLE.